# Inconsistent returns from loop sorting names

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet with a large list of names I'd like to organize into separate sheets by last name.   For example, I need a new sheet for last names A-C, D-F, etc.

I wrote a small script for this.  It works perfectly for A-C, but D-F ends up with names into H, and by M-O I'm getting names through Z.  Here's the loop:

```
 for (var i = 2; i<=end; i++){
var cur = s1.getRange(i,fic);
var data = cur.getValue();
var crow = cur.getRow();
if (data != ref){
         count++
          ref = data;
        if (count != 3){        
       var li = data;
      Logger.log("Current row is "+crow+", li is "+li);
       continue;
       }
       else if (count == 3 || i == end2){
       var lr = crow-2
       var cto = ss.insertSheet(first+"-"+li);
          Logger.log("Line 29 lr is "+lr);
       var names = s1.getRange(fr, 6,lr,1);
       Logger.log("Line 31 lr is "+lr);
       var nrows = names.getRowIndex();
       names.copyValuesToRange(cto, 1, 1,1, nrows);
       first = data;
       Logger.log("Line 35 lr is "+lr);
       fr = crow;
       Logger.log("First row of next page is "+fr);
       count = 0;
       continue;
```

Any idea why it's overextending responses more with each loop?

Comment: this looks like a classic excercise in debugging your code. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ to get a few more hints on debugging. Starting with Logging is great but using a debugger is even better and will help you a lot on your journey into programming. For google-apps-script i found this video tutorial which might help you.

Debugging questions are usually not very well recieved here. But once you reach a point you can't crack come again and ask your questions as meaningful and precise as possible. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the list of names sorted before your script runs?

Comment: Yes, the list of names is sorted A-Z by last name.

Answer (score 0):

formula solution/alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:A, IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(A2:A), " (.)"))}, 
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2", 0))
```

[image: 0]